# Determine the determinant and the inverse to the matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently working on determining the determinant and the inverse to the matrix A.

$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & a & b\\0 & 0 & 0 & c & d\\\end{bmatrix}$

The determinant is $ad-bc$. But how do I find out the inverse? I guess there should be some kind of way to see what the inverse would be...

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am a beginner in this area a good explanation is always helpful :)!

Comment: Considering the 1's, the inversion is simple!

Comment: Please show me @Ali :)

Comment: I think anon already did that. Also, in this case the determinant of the inverse is $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP asked in [several](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431398/determine-the-determinant-and-the-inverse-to-the-matrix-a#comment922610_431405) [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431398/determine-the-determinant-and-the-inverse-to-the-matrix-a#comment922611_431403) whether this can be done by Gauss elimination/row operations, I wil also provide this computation. I will only do this for the right lower block.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
a & b & 1 & 0\\
c & d & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
ac & bc & c & 0\\
ac & ad & 0 & a
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
ac & bc & c & 0\\
0 & ad-bc &-c & a
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
ac & bc & c & 0\\
0 & 1 &-\frac{c}{ad-bc} & \frac{a}{ad-bc}
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
ac & 0 & \frac{acd}{ad-bc} & -\frac{abc}{ad-bc}\\
0 & 1 &-\frac{c}{ad-bc} & \frac{a}{ad-bc}
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0 & \frac{d}{ad-bc} & -\frac{b}{ad-bc}\\
0 & 1 &-\frac{c}{ad-bc} & \frac{a}{ad-bc}
\end{array}\right)
$$
The above calculation shows that
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that the operations we did are only valid if $ad-bc\ne0$ (since we have divided by this expression).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:see  [block matrix inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix_pseudoinverse) $$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & a & b\\0 & 0 & 0 & c & d\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\0 & C \end{bmatrix}\to A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\0 & C^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$$ such that $C=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: what is the inverse of $A=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$? Does putting the inverse $A^{-1}$ in the corner of the matrix in place of what's already there create the desired inverse matrix? Check.

For a theoretical way to see why one might guess this, consider direct sums. If we let the matrix be a transformation of ${\bf R}^3\oplus{\bf R}^2$, it can be written in the form ${\rm Id}\oplus A$, which has inverse ${\rm Id}\oplus A^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi anon! The rule of the inverse to $A:=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ has not been presented. I think I should be doing this by gauss jordan elimination. But the steps are quite hard. Do you know any resource on this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First off the inverse only exists if $_____________$?

Assuming the above hypothesis, start out by finding the inverse of $A:=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$.

I'm assuming this was given earlier or appeared in a previous exercise, therefore you should know that $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}  d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}=(\det (A))^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}  d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$.

Now consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &d\det (A))^{-1} & -b\det (A))^{-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 &-c\det (A))^{-1} & a\det (A))^{-1} \end{bmatrix}\color{grey}{=\begin{bmatrix} I_3 & 0\\ 0 & A^{-1}\end{bmatrix}_{5\times 5}}.$

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I know that the inverse only exists if the determinant is not 0. The rule above about the inverse to $A:=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ I did not know and has not been presented. I guess I should get that result using gauss jordan elimination which is quite cumbersome... Thank you!

Comment: @LukasArvidsson You can multiply $A$ by $(\det (A))^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}  d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$ to get $I_2$ and $(\det (A))^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}  d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$ by $A$ to get $I_2$, hence proving that $A^{-1}=(\det (A))^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}  d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the determinant use Laplace expansion. Then, make an inversion on each block.